# How to convert a vector into a matrix by using two indices?

Tags: r

I have a data set look like this:

```
a<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
b<-rep(1:3,3)
c<-c(rep(c("i","j","k","l"),2),"o")
d<-data.frame(a,b,c)
```

which gives:

```
  a b c
1 1 1 i
2 1 2 j
3 1 3 k
4 2 1 l
5 2 2 i
6 2 3 j
7 3 1 k
8 3 2 l
9 3 3 o
```

I am looking for a way to transform c into the following form:

```
  1 2 3
1 i j k
2 l i j
3 k l o
```

So basically I hope to use `a` as the row index, `b` as column index, then transform the column `c` to a matrix. Is there any way this could be done efficiently by using data.table or other packages?

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: With only "c" you could do `matrix(c, ncol = 3, byrow = T)`...

Comment: That is very straight forward..Thanks a lot !! @docendod

Comment: If you do want to use `a` and `b` as indices, you can do `dcast(d,a~b,value.var = 'c')[-1]` (`dcast` is from `reshape2`). Also, use `as.matrix(...)` to obtain result in the matrix form

Answer (score 1):

@doscendo's solution is pretty clean; you just have to make sure the data frame is sorted properly.  Here is a slightly more generic version that uses a matrix index to create what you're after and will work both if the data frame doesn't specify every value, or if a value is specified more than once (last value prevails), or if the data isn't sorted (although of course for the last one you can always sort):

```
mx <- with(d, matrix(ncol=max(a), nrow=max(b)))
mx[as.matrix(d[1:2])] <- as.character(d$c)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "i"  "j"  "k" 
[2,] "l"  "i"  "j" 
[3,] "k"  "l"  "o"
```

Answer (score 0):

As docendo said you can use just c for row-major layout

```
matrix(c, 3, byrow=T)
```

Or if you desperately desire to use a and b vectors i suggest next trick

```
mymatrix = matrix(rep(0, 9), 3)  # creating init matrix of required size
for(i in seq_along(a)){mymatrix[a[i],b[i]]=c[i]} # fill out the matrix
```

Comment: Oh, you're right, my bad, Because of almost symmetric data failed to notice the difference. Fixed the answer